YT Iframe API: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.getOwnPropertyNames
I have an YouTube iframe on my site which I'd like to control with YT Iframe API. I follow their guide, everything seems to work well, but there is an annoying error in Chrome browser console: console error. It's not permanent, happens when video is started or paused, after clicking somewhere outside the iframe and then inside again trying to make it playing or pause, but NOT every time. According to console hints, the files where the error takes place, are not mine, but those of YT API. Did anybody else already bump into this error and knows how to fix it?? I'm getting frustrated as I could not find the solution in the Internet ((
I tried to copy completely the example from YT Iframe API guide, but the error is still there.


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <style>
    iframe {
      border-width: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="myVid" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
    style="border: solid 24px #37474F"></iframe>

  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  <script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player("myVid", {
        events: {
          onReady: onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
        },
      });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      document.getElementById("myVid").style.borderColor = "#FF6D00";
    }
    function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
      var color;
      if (playerStatus == -1) {
        color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
      } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
        color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
      } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
        color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
      } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
        color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
      } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
        color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
      } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
        color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
      }
      if (color) {
        document.getElementById("myVid").style.borderColor = color;
      }
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      changeBorderColor(event.data);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>




Please [edit] your question and add the code you're using

@MauricioAriasOlave, done. But the snippet doesn't run at all here, though in my local machine it starts.

Thanks for add your code. I've tested on jsfiddle.net an it works without errors - see the running snippet on jsfiddle.net.

@MauricioAriasOlave, thank you very much for quick testing! It's strange, but the error is still in my browser console (( It may be something wrong in my browser. I wish I could attach video from my screen to show the steps when the error happens. Or is it possibile to attach video here?

you could upload a YouTube video - capturing your results - and then share the link of your uploaded video. Have you tried your code in different browers? - would be good to try on different browsers and [edit] your question with the browser versions you've tried. Also, try to disable external extensions you might have installed in your browser (adblock, for example) and see if there is any changes. If you want as well, try to test your code on a different computer and see the results. Finally, try to reinstall your browser. Hope it helps.

@MauricioAriasOlave
I'll try everything you suggest. Thanks again for the attention to my issue!
